# WSL open at specific directory

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to open up a terminal in a WSL.

I know I can open it up at the root by doing `wsl.exe ~`, but is there a way I can open it up at a specific folder?

For instance, I have a directory at `~/Dev`, so I want to open up WSL at that location.

When I try `wsl.exe ~/Dev`, I get the following error

```
/bin/bash: /home/myname/Dev: Is a directory

[process exited with code 126]
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?
C:\Users is specified folder in this case.

```
cmd /k "cd C:\Users && wsl"
```

Answer (score 2):

In WSL2,

> --cd 
> Sets the specified directory as the current working directory.
> If ~ is used the Linux user's home path will be used. If the path begins
> with a / character, it will be interpreted as an absolute Linux path.
> Otherwise, the value must be an absolute Windows path.

You can actually use something like this

```
wsl --cd /home/YourUsername/Desktop
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Given the [Command Reference for Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference) I don't think this is possible:

- Launching without parameters launches a shell in the current directory
- `~` is a special parameter telling wsl to launch the shell in the uses home directory
- Any other parameter(s) then `~` are treated as a command that will be executed inside wsl and its output returned to the current shell

It is however possible to customize the home directory of the user using [usermod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod), but it is not technically an answer to your question